# Upgrade Flutter project - copy native files?

Tags: flutter

After upgrading Flutter(flutter upgrade) sometimes there is errors and a new clean project is needed.

Is there any list of native files(like Classes in a Plugin) you should copy to the new project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It looks like nowadays you just have to `upgrade` and then run `create` at the project's folder.

```
flutter upgrade

cd yourproject
flutter create .
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Exactly!!

I've been facing this for quite a while (since I'm an early adopter), and I wondered how people managed these flutter upgrades. One day you upgrade flutter and your app does not build anymore.

Right from the beginning I created a script `after_flutter_upgrade.sh`, that I keep in the main folder of the project and I run it when that happens. Every iteration requires a few extra steps, and I keep maintaining the script. As it is very project-dependent, and I don't think it will help posting it here.

It feels terribly wrong doing that, but it works, so I forgive myself.

What the script does is going to the parent folder and renaming the project's folder to something like `old_<myproject>`. Then, it runs `flutter create <myproject>`. So I remain with the original `old_<myproject>` and the recently created blank `<myproject>`.

And then the script start copying from the old to the new one:

```bash
/lib
/test
/assets      # I keep an assets folder for logos, images and such
/.vscode     # If you use it
/.git        # Afterall I want to log everything which was changed

/.gitignore
/android/.gitignore
/analysis_options.yaml   # if you defined it
/pubspec.yaml
/README.md

/android/key.properties    # if you're using it that way

# icons
/android/app/src/main/res
/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

# These two if you're using firebase
/android/app/google-services.json   
/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

THEN, you still need:

1. Update `ios/Runner/Info.plist` for the `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleLocalizations`entries.
2. Update `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` with your `package` and `android:label`.
3. Update `android/app/src/main/com/example/prokect/MainActivity.java` or `android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/project/MainActivity.kt` with your `package` and adjusting the folder name (`/com/example` -> `/com/mycompany`)
4. Update `android/app/build.gradle`: changing `applicationId` with your package
5. Update `android/app/build.gradle`: changing `signingConfig` and `signingConfigs` to the same ones you've been using
6. Update `android/app/build.gradle`: adding `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` if you're using firebase
7. Updating `android/build.gradle`: add google-services `classpath` in `dependencies` if you're using firebase
8. Adding `GoogleService-info.plist` to the iOS project. Run `open -a Xcode ./ios` and just drag this file from Finder to Xcode's Runner folder, so that Xcode recognises it.
9. Update `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`: search for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER and adjust with your package name
10. Update `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`: search for ORGANIZATIONNAME and adjust with your package name
11. Correct the package in the following files:

- android/app/src/profile/AndroiManifest.xml
- android/app/src/main/AndroiManifest.xml
- android/app/src/debug/AndroiManifest.xml

12. Update `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`: add a new style:

```xml
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And at least with me, this works. Hope it saves some time for someone.

Of course in your project there might be additional steps.

When I started the script, it was just 5 steps, now it's 12 and in 2021 they may get to 20!! :)